# How to store and retrieve values from an object in using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to store the names and heights of several div tags in an object for later use. I am attempting to do this by finding the divs with class "hidden," then registering their names and heights in an .each loop. However, when I attempt to my code, I will either get the same div tag's name and value repeated several times, or I will just get the initial values of the object.

```
    var heightMap = {name:'x',value:'y'};
    function setHeightMap() {
        $( ".hidden" ).each(function() {
            $setName = $( this ).attr('id');
            $setValue = $( this ).height();
        });
        $heightMap.push({'name':$setName, 'value':$setValue});
    };
    console.log(heightMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`map`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) function to loop over all the elements with the CSS class `.hidden` and return an object with the `name` and `value` for each element. The result will be and array with objects.

```
var heightMap = $(".hidden").map((index, element) => {
  const $element = $(element);
  const name = $element.attr('id');
  const value = $element.height();
  return ({ name, value });
});
```

Comment: Elegant solution. I might suggest reducing the lines to just a single return line: `return { name: $(element).attr("id"), value: $(element).height() };`

Comment: I respect the suggestion as it makes the callback shorter, but it does require calling `$(element)`more than once which makes the code less DRY. If we could do it without jQuery, then we would be able to write it as a single line, without any repetition ;).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  var heightMap = [];

  function setHeightMap() {
    $(".hidden").each(function(i, el) {
      heightMap.push({
        name: $(el).attr("id"),
        height: $(el).height()
      });
    });
  };

  setHeightMap();
  console.log(heightMap);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="hidden" style="width: 20px; height: 30px;" id="obj-1"></div>
  <div class="hidden" style="width: 30px; height: 60px;" id="obj-2"></div>
  <div class="hidden" style="width: 40px; height: 120px;" id="obj-3"></div>
  <div class="hidden" style="width: 50px; height: 240px;" id="obj-4"></div>
</div>
```

You cannot use `.push()` on an Object. You will want to set this to be an Array and then you can push Objects into it.

You will want to use `.push()` inside your Each loop.

You can also use `.map()` in a similar method.

```js
$(function() {
  var heightMap = $(".hidden").map(function(i, el) {
    return {
      name: $(el).attr("id"),
      height: $(el).height()
    };
  });

  console.log(heightMap.get());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="hidden" style="width: 20px; height: 30px;" id="obj-1"></div>
  <div class="hidden" style="width: 30px; height: 60px;" id="obj-2"></div>
  <div class="hidden" style="width: 40px; height: 120px;" id="obj-3"></div>
  <div class="hidden" style="width: 50px; height: 240px;" id="obj-4"></div>
</div>
```

> As the return value is a jQuery object, which contains an array, it's very common to call `.get()` on the result to work with a basic array.

See more: https://api.jquery.com/map/

Answer (score -1):

You must push the values inside the `each` loop.

The original code only added a single height descriptor object: The one based on the values from the last iteration.

Moreover ...

- `heightMap` should  be an array
- `heightMap` and `$heightMap` are differwnt entities !
- The function `setHeightMap` must actually be called.

Corrected version:

```
    var heightMap = [{name:'x',value:'y'}];
    function setHeightMap() {
        $( ".hidden" ).each(function() {
           $setName = $( this ).attr('id');
           $setValue = $( this ).height();

           // Must be called inside the loop !
           heightMap.push({'name':$setName, 'value':$setValue});
        });
    }
    setHeightMap();

    console.log(heightMap);
```

Comment: That makes sense, but the result is still just "x" and "y" when I'm looking for the ID's of the divs with class ".hidden"

Comment: Yeah, missed the other issues at first glance. Updated

Comment: That wasn't quite right, but it helped me find the solution I was looking for. After making your changes I removed the outer function setHeightMap, and that set everything properly. Thanks!

Comment: Oppos, another one. Updated